# Can't change galaxy s4 lock screen wallpaper if security is in place

Tags: lock-screens, wallpaper, samsung-galaxy-s-4

If I use no security for galaxy s4 lock screen I can use a custom wallpaper for the lock screen. But if I use a Pin security then the lock screen uses the default wallpaper of a kid running with a bunch of balloons when entering my pin. Can someone confirm this please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've read this is a known "issue" with the S4.  When using pin security you can't change any lock screen widgets either.  If I was sure that my Fitbit Flex would continue to work with the S4 I'd have flashed CyanogenMod onto my S4 (they have been producing nightly versions for the S4 for a couple of weeks now).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Surprisingly i restarted the device and the problem fixed itself. Hooray